# Prove an inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

for $x > -1$, Prove the following inequality:

$$\left( {\ln (1 + x) + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^k}{x^k}}}{k}} } \right){( - x)^{n + 1}} \le 0$$

Following the advice to use Lagrange's reminder:

$${R_n} = \frac{{\ln {{(1 + c)}^{(n)}}}}{{(n + 1)!}}{x^{n + 1}}$$.

So, the all expression now looks like this:

$$\frac{{\ln {{(1 + c)}^{(n+1)}}}}{{(n + 1)!}}{x^{n + 1}}{( - x)^{n + 1}}$$

Taking into account that:

$$\ln {(1 + c)^{(n+1)}} =  - \frac{1}{{{{(c + 1)}^{n + 1}}}}$$

We get:

$$- \frac{1}{{(n + 1)!{{(c + 1)}^{n + 1}}}}{x^{n + 1}}{( - x)^{n + 1}}$$

So, when $n \in \mathbb{N}_{odd}$, it's true that the expression is negative.
What about the case where $n \in \mathbb{N}_{even}$

Comment: Hint: Taylor's theorem with Lagrange reminder

Comment: The expression in the inequality involves a *finite* sum, so there's no concern with convergence or divergence.  You're simply asked to prove a sequence of inequalities, presumably for all $n\ge1$.

Comment: Can you refer my edit, please?

Comment: Now try to find an explicit formula for this n-th derivative.

Comment: You're almost there; derivative formula is not quite correct. The sign is not just $-$, it alternates, as the power of $x$ is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

Your formula for the error was a bit off, but you fixed it now.
So you need to show that
$$
\frac{{\ln^{(n+1)} {{(1 + c)}}}}{{(n + 1)!}}{x^{n + 1}}{( - x)^{n + 1}} \le 0
$$

First show by induction that
$$
\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^{n+1} \ln(1 + t)
= (-1)^{n} n! (1 + t)^{-(n+1)}
$$

So your expression simplifies to
$$
\frac{(-1)^n n!}{{(n + 1)!(1 + c)^{n+1}}}{x^{n + 1}}{( - x)^{n + 1}}
=
\frac{(-1)^n}{{(n + 1)(1 + c)^{n+1}}}{x^{n + 1}}{( - x)^{n + 1}}
$$

You just have to show this is nonnegative.  Note that:

- $x^{2n + 2} \ge 0$.
- $(-1)^n (-1)^{n+1} = -1$.
- $c$ is strictly between $0$ and $x$, implying $c > -1$.

Comment: Oh I see where were my mistakes. I totally forgot about the $(-1)^n$.. Thanks!